# Need to replace quotation marks with commas in a csv file

Tags: mysql, powershell, csv

I had a .tsv file that I tried to convert to .csv through browser services but the file is too large (approx 500 MB) to be processed. I found this code on StackOverflow to convert it into csv with PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\file\ -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter "`t"
} | Export-Csv C:\path\to\output.csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

However this turned the tabs into quotation marks, and in order to upload it to mysql I need this files columns/rows to be separated by commas (as far as I'm aware). How can I go about doing this?

Currently looks like this but I need all the quotation marks to be commas instead:

[image]

Comment: Use `-Delimiter ","`.  The `Export-Csv` cmdlet always  encloses every particular **field** in a pair of double quotes.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have another error to deal with, but you did solve my problem.

Comment: Please explain what your problem actually is. Open your CSV in a text editor, then [edit] your question and show us samples of a) what the text content actually looks like and b) what you want the text content to look like.